# Network Shares stopped auto mounting on boot

Tags: networking, mount, fstab

I have looked though posts and tried several things but to no avail.  Am running Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS with Cinnamon desktop and Nemo file manager.  Everything was working fine, all drives and network shares were auto mounting on boot as they should.

After changing my user password no drives or network shares would auto mount.  Furthermore the mount locations for my hard drives had disappeared.  To get everything working again I had to add entries in fstab for all my hard drives and recreate my mount points.  Before that there were no entries in fstab for hard drives, they were apparently being mounted by some other process.  After entering hard drives in fstab they auto mount just fine.  However, network shares are still not mounting.

Network shares will mount after login if I do sudo mount command.  As per another post I tried using login script rc.local to mount drives after login.  That script runs and works, except during login it throws this error:

Mar 15 12:05:35 ZFC-charliek-Ubuntu rc.local[1389]: mount error: could not resol
Mar 15 12:05:35 ZFC-charliek-Ubuntu systemd[1]: rc-local.service: Control proces
Mar 15 12:05:35 ZFC-charliek-Ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start 
35 ZFC-charliek-Ubuntu systemd[1]: rc-local.service: Failed with re

So the script is failing to run at start up and mount the drives due to some kind of resolve error?

Any ideas what is going wrong here?  Why did drives stop auto mounting on boot?  I am a linux noob, thanks for your help.

Edit: contents of fstab

```
//backup1/NetworkDeviceBU /media/NetworkDeviceBU cifs credentials=/home/charliek/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,se‌​c=ntlm,user 0 0
 //fruit/ha/Home\040FOlder/charliek /media/charliek_home cifs credentials=/home/charliek/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,se‌​c=ntlm,user,uid=1000‌​,gid=1000 0 0
//fruit/ha/IS\040Department /media/ISDepartment cifs auto,credentials=/home/charliek/.smbcredentials,_netdev,ioch‌​arset=utf8,sec=ntlm,‌​user 0 0
 //fruit/ha/user\040programs /media/UserPrograms cifs credentials=/home/charliek/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,se‌​c=ntlm,user 0 0
```

Comment: Have you tried mounting the shares using fstab?

Comment: I have run sudo mount -a and sudo mount  sharename after booting, which as I understand it cause the system to read the fstab file and mount what it finds there.  Those commands work fine.

Comment: OK, thanks, I was not sure if you were listing the shares in fstab.  If you are, editing your question to include a listing of fstab might help. (remove any private info first)

Comment: //backup1/NetworkDeviceBU /media/NetworkDeviceBU cifs credentials=/home/charliek/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,user 0 0
//fruit/ha/Home\040FOlder/charliek /media/charliek_home cifs credentials=/home/charliek/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,user,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
//fruit/ha/IS\040Department /media/ISDepartment cifs auto,credentials=/home/charliek/.smbcredentials,_netdev,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,user 0 0
//fruit/ha/user\040programs /media/UserPrograms cifs credentials=/home/charliek/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,user 0 0

Comment: Well some progress.  I tried using a sudo crontab job to mount the drives 60 seconds after reboot.  The error that job spits out is:
mount error: could not resolve address for backup1: Unknown error
mount error: could not resolve address for fruit: Unknown error
mount error: could not resolve address for fruit: Unknown error
mount error: could not resolve address for fruit: Unknown error

I thought the _netdev option in fstab was supposed to curtail this.  If I try using the ip address of fruit or backup1 in fstab the shares will not mount at all.

Comment: I am thinking along the same lines, like the network shares are not available when mount tries to mount them during boot.  In 14.04 I used option nobootfail for that but it doesn't exist in 16.04.  There is a nofail option but I am not sure it does the same thing.

Comment: The following Thread might help in similar cases: [Networks Shares do not mount during boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040134/cifs-does-not-mount-network-device-at-boot/1081178#1081178)